# list of numpy vectors to sparse array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a list of numpy vectors of the format:

```
    [array([[-0.36314615,  0.80562619, -0.82777381, ...,  2.00876354,2.08571887, -1.24526026]]), 
     array([[ 0.9766923 , -0.05725135, -0.38505339, ...,  0.12187988,-0.83129255,  0.32003683]]),
     array([[-0.59539878,  2.27166874,  0.39192573, ..., -0.73741573,1.49082653,  1.42466276]])]
```

here, only 3 vectors in the list are shown. I have 100s..

The maximum number of elements in one vector is around 10 million

All the arrays in the list have unequal number of elements but the maximum number of elements is fixed.
Is it possible to create a sparse matrix using these vectors in python such that I have zeros in place of elements for the vectors which are smaller than the maximum size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
from scipy import sparse
M = sparse.lil_matrix((num_of_vectors, max_vector_size))

for i,v in enumerate(vectors):
     M[i, :v.size] = v
```

Then take a look at this page: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

The `lil_matrix` format is good for constructing the matrix, but you'll want to convert it to a different format like `csr_matrix` before operating on them.

Comment: should the lil_matrix be converted to csr_matrix like this: M.tocsr() ?

Comment: Also, is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: @AbhishekThakur: Well, how did you get the list of vectors in the first place? If you could populate the sparse matrix directly...also, is there a certain performance criteria you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

In this approach you replace the elements below your thresold by `0` and then create a sparse matrix out of them. I am suggesting the `coo_matrix` since it is the fastest to convert to the other types according to your purposes. Then you can `scipy.sparse.vstack()` them to build your matrix accounting all elements in the list:

```
import scipy.sparse as ss
import numpy as np

old_list = [np.random.random(100000) for i in range(5)]

threshold = 0.01
for a in old_list:
    a[np.absolute(a) < threshold] = 0
old_list = [ss.coo_matrix(a) for a in old_list]
m = ss.vstack( old_list )
```

Comment: @AbhishekThakur I just double-tested here and it works... I've updated the answer adding one line showing how to create the old_list... try to run and then print the `m` sparse matrix to see how it looks like...

Answer (score 1):

A little convoluted, but I would probably do it like this:

```
>>> import scipy.sparse as sps
>>> a = [np.arange(5), np.arange(7), np.arange(3)]
>>> lens = [len(j) for j in a]
>>> cols = np.concatenate([np.arange(j) for j in lens])
>>> rows = np.concatenate([np.repeat(j, len_) for j, len_ in enumerate(lens)])
>>> data = np.concatenate(a)
>>> b = sps.coo_matrix((data,(rows, cols)))
>>> b.toarray()
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: actually my final matrix will be of size: 10k x 10mil . So I dont think this is a feasible way...

Comment: If you skip the `.toarray`, which I just added to show that what gets stored in `b` is what you wanted, you are not incurring in too much overhead. It could be rewritten to generate the indices of a CSR matrix directly, but that would be much less clear.